# How to bring left sidebar below the content for mobile view in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my bootstrap web page i have a left sidebar and besides it i have the page content. The HTML code is:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">Sidebar</div>
<div class="col-sm-9">Content</div>
```

I like the view for laptops and bigger screens but on screens <768 px wide (tablets and smartphones). The divs slack and the sidebar comes on top of content div.

I know this is a bootstrap feature but i want it to slack another way- i want the content to be at top of sidebar on screens <768 px wide.

You can view this thing on the [jQuery](http://www.yogihosting.com/category/jquery/) page. Opening the page on smaller browser view will show what i mean.

Can this be done in bootstrap? I definitely want to the design to remain same for laptop and bigger screen.

And i don't want to apply any custom media query for this. Can bootstrap provides a solution for things like this? Please help. thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a working solution?

Answer (score 3):

### Push and Pull solution

If you can reorder the divs in your html you can utilize the `push` and `pull` from bootstrap.

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-push-3">Content</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-pull-9">Sidebar</div>
```

Comment: i want only sm-* column here.

Comment: @yogihosting Why can't you add `col-xs-*`? This is the easiest/best way together with Boostrap to manipulate the layout without touching the css.

Comment: i want the divs to slack but in opposite manner. Your solution will not allow then to slack at all.

Comment: @yogihosting I updated my post with a bootstrap solution.

Comment: thank you you gave me knowledge of push and i am able to solve it now.

Answer (score 2):

**Update Bootstrap V4 Alpha**

Change the order of your grid columns using the push-md-* and the pull-md-* modifier classes.

**Example**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9 push-md-3">Right Content</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 pull-md-9">Left Sidebar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you you gave me knowledge of push and i am able to solve my problem. Although i am using bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `direction: rtl;` on you container, and `direction: ltr;` on your columns, with the appropriate media queries.

HTML:

```
<div class="row-rtl">
  <div class="col-ltr">Main</div>
  <div class="col-ltr">Sidebar</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row-rtl {
  direction: rtl;
}
.col-ltr {
  direction: ltr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the `col-md-push-*`, i also changed the order of my columns first then applied the push. This is the final code.

```
<div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-push-3">Content</div>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-pull-9">Sidebar</div>
```

What is is doing with `push` and `pull` is that when the screen size is greater than `sm` meaning in `md-*` and `lg-*` then is is pushing the content div and pulling the sidebar - meaning for `screen size ≥992px` sidebar div comes first then comes the content div.

For in `sm` screen size (<768px) it behaves normally based on what the order is specified in the html.